# Importing AppCompat is not working in Eclipse

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-actionbar, memcached, android-appcompat

I want to check for a network connection first, then I want to do the xml parsing inside an AsyncTask.
Add top menu.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://www.rtsoftbd.com/parliament.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "members"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "constituency";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "party";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    // private String[] arraySpinner;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // or getActionBar();
        // getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My new title"); // set the top title
        // String title = actionBar.getTitle().toString(); // get the title
        // actionBar.hide();
        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        // getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.icon);
        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);//
        // getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
        // R.layout.window_title);
        // spinner menu
        // this.arraySpinner = new String[] { "Call", "Send Email", "Feedback",
        // "Setting", "About" };
        // Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        // ArrayAdapter<String> sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        // android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
        // s.setAdapter(sadapter);

        // end of spinner menu
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        SecondActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("Integer", position);
                summaryIntent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(summaryIntent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position:" + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            private View getListView() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    public void home(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "home button clicked, sorry under construction",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void aboutdevloper(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "About Developer: Md. Imraj Hossain", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent summaryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DevActivity.class);
        startActivity(summaryIntent);
    }

    public void message(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "message button clicked, sorry under construction",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void goback(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "goback button clicked, sorry under construction",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void close(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "goback button clicked, sorry under construction",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you get unexpected results? What is the expected result then? Do you get any errors? Add them! A [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (try to isolate the problem) is always appreciated.

Comment: i have several question here. first, after i added library for appcompat v7 i got a lib directory having appcompat file. then when i try to rename the Activity to appCompatActivity it shows me several error. i don't understand what's wrong in eclipse. i also changed my  min sdk to 14. but nothing work out.i have several more question about this ...thanks